# Laravel post with content type json

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm working with laravel 5 framework, i want to create a rest API and i'm getting some problems.
I have a method post that receives Json and i can't access that content, always say is `[]` or `null`

That's my controller function:

```
public function Register()
{            
    $teste = Request::json()->all();     
    $name=$teste['wtf'];
    return  $name;            
}
```

That returns me this error "Undefined index: wtf" because the array $teste is null

How can I receive JSON properly?

Comment: how are you passing the data to the url ?

Comment: I'm using chrome extension webClient and create a post with key= "wtf" Value="Hello World" , and trying to request all content and return only "wtf"

Comment: what is the result of: `dd( Request::input('wtf') );` ?

Comment: this it what response gave me:

Comment: i don't see anything :)

Comment: that returns me an html script element. It isn't equal to the parameter I passed

Comment: so, probably you are not passing the value correctly from the client. You should get the string 'Hello World'

Comment: I do this, i think i'm doing it right can you check that print pls

https://gyazo.com/bd5dd0db6bdf08be4c29a382f2531503

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the image you showed in the comment, I realize that the data you are sending is as `form-data` and not `JSON`. Please select `raw` option and choose `json` instead of `text` from drop down and retry what @Moppo said

Comment: I'm so blind xd, how couldn't i see that. Thanks you made my day